# ClearAll["Global`*"] automatic insert

Tags: variables, wolfram-mathematica

I don't know where to find and adjust the configuration file to have Mathematica insert ClearAll["Global`*"]
at the beginning of every new notebook.  How can I do this, rather than having to type it everytime I open a new notebook?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to change the default new Notebook. But it is possible to add custom keyboard shortcut and/or menu command which will create new Notebook which will contain whatever you need. For example, you can add menu item "New my Notebook" under the "File -> New" submenu and assign `Ctrl+Shift+N` keyboard shortcut to evaluate it (this modification will only persist during current `FrontEndSession`) by evaluating the following (taken from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35239/280) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2147/280)):

```
FrontEndExecute[
 FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands[
  "New", {MenuItem["My new Notebook", 
    System`KernelExecute[
     CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[Defer@ClearAll["Global`*"], "Input"]]], 
    FrontEnd`MenuKey["N", FrontEnd`Modifiers -> {"Control", "Shift"}],
     System`MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]}]]
```

Now pressing `Ctrl+Shift+N` will open new Notebook window with `"Input"` cell already containing `` ClearAll["Global`*"] ``. If you replace `` FrontEnd`Modifiers -> {"Control", "Shift"} `` with `` FrontEnd`Modifiers -> {"Command"} ``, the keyboard combination will be `Alt+N`.

Information on how to make this change permanent can be found in [this](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Apr/msg00400.html) MathGroups post:

> You can completely reset the menus using...
>
> FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`ResetMenusPacket[{Automatic}]]
>
> You'll get some ugly flicker, but that would work.  You can also put
>   the  AddMenuCommands function in a front end init.m which can be found
>   someplace on  the path specified in the ConfigurationPath option.  In
>   that case, the init.m  file will get executed by the FE as it starts,
>   not the kernel, and so it won't  matter how many kernels you start or
>   quit.

So you need to create the `init.m` file in one of the paths given by the `ConfigurationPath` option:

```
Options[$FrontEnd, ConfigurationPath][[1, 2]]
```

> ```
> {FrontEnd`FileName[{$InstallationDirectory, "Configuration", "FrontEnd"}], 
>  FrontEnd`FileName[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Autoload", _, "Configuration", "FrontEnd"}], 
>  FrontEnd`FileName[{$BaseDirectory, "Autoload", _, "Configuration", "FrontEnd"}], 
>  FrontEnd`FileName[{$InstallationDirectory, "AddOns", "Autoload", _, "Configuration", "FrontEnd"}]}
> ```

Some of these paths contain blank (`_`) which is undocumented but seemingly means *any name* (I have not not checked this).

Another way to make this change permanent is to edit your `MenuSetup.tr` file, but it is [not recommended](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1409/280).

P.S. I recommend you in future to ask your *Mathematica*-related questions on dedicated site, where they will receive more attention:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/